# android studio unable to find local maven repository

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I placed the files of the repository in the .m2 folder but android studio is unable to resolve it

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.redcpt:sdk:0.0.1
```

does anyone know what might be the issue

Comment: Why did you place the files manually? Maven will do it for you. It would be helpful to share  related parts of `pom.xml`/ `settings.xml` if present. Also android studio by default uses gradle as build tool. The exception you have shared comes from gradle, are you sure you are using Maven?

Comment: I dont have much experience with maven, my company shared with me a sdk folder and in the install steps they said to place it in the .m2 folder, I didnt have a .m2 folder, so I installed maven and placed it there.

Comment: the structure of that folder is sdk -> 0.0.1 ->.pom, .jar, .aar files here.

Comment: A dependency with coordinates `com.redcpt:sdk:0.0.1` should exist in `.m2/repository/com/redcpt/sdk/0.0.1/`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you very much, I feel so stupid for wasting 2 days due to this, please post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you mention *"the structure of that folder is sdk -> 0.0.1 ->.pom, .jar, .aar files here."*. That is the wrong location. A Maven dependency with coordinates `com.redcpt:sdk:0.0.1` should be saved in `.m2/repository/com/redcpt/sdk/0.0.1/`.

It might be simpler to use Maven to install files into your local repository, see also [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) (although I don't know what needs to be done to store the `.aar` file that way).

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio automatically places the Maven repositories in the correct location when you download them from Maven. There's no reason to go into any local maven folders.

Start a new project from scratch while connected online and see if that helps. You will be given updated options on dependencies sourced from Maven.